# Feeding a real-time plot with data from another script

Tags: python, arrays, plot, signal-processing, fft

1. I'm pulling acceleration data from a sensor connected to an ESP32 via a serial port. Script 1 builds a fixed size array from these data and refreshes it as soon as new data comes in.

   ARRAY shape (1024, 4):

   idx 1 [ data_x, data, _y data_z, time ] **del**
   ...
   ...
   ...
   idx 1024 [ data_x, data _y, data_z, time ] **add**
2. now I want to pass this refreshing array to Script 2 which is an animated plot showing a realtime FFT of the acceleration data

It kind of works if I'm writing every single data line to a CSV and pulling the data with Script 2 from it, the CSV eventually gets bloated, and the plotting lags.

I tried to write the whole array into the CSV over and over again but often script 2 cant pull the data making the plot laggy or plain wrong.

Script 1:

```py
while True:
    if s.readline() == b'st\r\n':
        payload = []
        while len(payload) < 3:
            payload.append(s.readline())

        try:
            ACCEL_X = float(payload[0])
            ACCEL_Y = float(payload[1])
            ACCEL_Z = float(payload[2])       
            ACCEL_X_SCALED = (ACCEL_X*g) / 16384.0
            ACCEL_Y_SCALED = (ACCEL_Y*g) / 16384.0
            ACCEL_Z_SCALED = (ACCEL_Z*g) / 16384.0 
            n += 1        
        except: 
            print('discarded - no data')

    if float(time.perf_counter()) > float(start_time + k):
        k += T
        print(k, n)  
        Fs = n
        n = 0

    chunk = np.array([ACCEL_X_SCALED, ACCEL_Y_SCALED, ACCEL_Z_SCALED, \
                      time.perf_counter() - start_time])

    chnkLst.append(chunk)
    if len(chnkLst) == samples + 1:
        del chnkLst[0]  
        chnkArr = np.asarray(chnkLst)
```

part of Script 2 pulling the data

```py
def animate(i):
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None)
    x = df[0].values
    y = df[1].values
    z = df[2].values
```

So what's the proper way of feeding the data into script 2?

Comment: seems like you want the async capability

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: thanks for the replies, i gave the csv solution another try. i just truncate the csv after 4096 rows. realtime plot runs buttersmooth now